# Pointers manipulation in c

Tags: c, pointers

I have a doubt in pointers manipulation...

```
main()
{   int x=10;  // extra line added...
   char *p=x;

   printf("%d", &p)

   printf("%d", &p[0]);
   printf("%d" , &p[1]);
}
```

This code gives output

Address of 10..
10
11

how are the last two outputs are coming.. Can anyone explain it to me ..?

Code changed.....

Comment: wat if i want such ...how it is working ...this code is correct..can u explain me ?

Comment: Please get yourself a book about C or read on online. Your code has at least three flaws that make the behavior undefined (C terminology that anything can happen, including eating your hard drive). `main` has a different signature than this here. To print pointer values use the `%p` format. `p[1]` is `*(p + 1)` and doing arithmetic on a pointer that contains no valid address.

Comment: The data type the pointer points to is char, the line you added should be char not integer.

Comment: Also, what is your purpose on the second line? Note that you must initialize p before you can assign value to what it points to. Use `malloc()` to initialize p or assign the address of x to p, like this `char *p = &x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will explain two scenarios:

### Scenario 1: `char * p = x;`

`x == 10`, `p` is a char pointer which is initialized with 10 (an address which user program can't access): `p == 10`

The value of `p` (ie, `*p`) will lead to segmentation fault (being invalid memory reference)

`p[0] == *(p + 0)` and `&p[0] == (p+0) == p`  which is 10.

Hence `printf("%p", &p[0])` will give you 10.

`p[1] == *(p + 1)` and `&p[1] == (p+1)`

Since, `p` is a character pointer, it gets increments by `sizeof(char)`, ie 1

Hence `printf("%p", &p[1])` will give you 10+1 = 11

### Scenario 2:  `char * p = &x;`

Here `p` is a char pointer pointing to integer `x`

Value of `x` = 10

Address of `x` = 1000 (assume)

Hence `p` = 1000

`p[0] == *(p + 0)` and `&p[0] == (p+0) == p`

Hence `printf("%p", &p[0])` will give you 1000

`p[1] == *(p + 1)` and `&p[1] == (p+1)`

Since, `p` is a character pointer, it gets increments by `sizeof(char)`, ie 1

ie `&p[1] == 1000+1 == 1001`

Answer (score 3):

This is Undefined Behavior.
The pointer needs to point to something valid before some value can be added to that location.

```
char a = 10;
char *p = &a;
```

Comment: let make it int a=10 & char *p=a then what would be the answer ?

Comment: can i get a better explanation to my question....it has been changed..for this...plz now provide me a better ... i m confused on &p and &p[0]

Answer (score 1):

`p` and `&p[0]` will be evaluated to same address (address of first element of array) which is 10.

So `&p[0]` will be evaluated to `10` and `&p[1]` to `&p[0] + sizeof(char)` which is 11

Your code will most likely segfault though when you dereference p (`*p`).

Following code will always print `True`.

```
main()
{  
    int* p; 
    printf("%s\n",p == &p[0] ? "True" : "False");
}
```

Comment: but on executing above code i m getting
address on &p
and value 10 on printing  &p[0] 
but as u said it shud print address  in both case but its not ..so ?why

Comment: In your example, `p` is a pointer to a char array. you assigned `10` to it. So now `p` points to a memory location 10 . `&p` is the address of p, where `10` is stored (`say 0x28cd24`). `&p` is not `10`.  `&p[0]` is address of first element which array `p` points to. That is nothing but `p` which would be `10`.

Comment: here is a png version of what I tried to explain, http://i49.tinypic.com/4rxp1f.png

Answer (score 0):

```
char *p=10;
```

The code at present has undefined behavior. Pointer `p` is not pointing to any valid memory location to initialize 10 in that location.

With that said, both `p`, `&p[0]` yields the same memory location.

Comment: The above doesn't store anything where p points to, it initializes p.

Comment: When said "initializes p", what is the value of the initialization ? I amn't sure I got you. Please explain.

Comment: The value of the initialization is 10. Which is probably a meaningless pointer, but so be it!

Comment: guys i have changed the code...now me the reason for such behaviour of the pinter..i.e.  &p and  &p[0]

Answer (score 0):

Some errors in your code:

```
int x = 10;
char * p = &x; // error  1 - you was assigning int to pointer

printf("%p\n", &p); //  error 2 - you printing address of pointer (char **), 
                    //  so different format string is needed
printf("%p\n",  &p[0]);  // same error 2 - printing address of first byte in int x
printf("%p\n" , &p[1]);  // same error 2 - printing address of second byte in int x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   printf("%d", &p[0]);
   printf("%d" , &p[1]);
```

it will print out the address that p is pointered on..
because char *p=x; while x = 10;

then ,, &p[0] = 10, &p[1] = 11 &p[2] = 12 , and so on..

```
   printf("%d", &p);
```

I'm not so sure about this, but as i know it will print out the value contained in memory 10 in my case = 10000

```
   printf("%d", p);
```

it will print out the 10, which is the *p value;

cmiiw